# tomcat: how can we log user name in tomcat log?

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have tried uncomment the valve line in the server.xml. The uncommented lines are

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

It only logs the url being accessed. It did not log down who have made the request.

What is the proper way to do it in tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected the "common" pattern ; you need to specify a custom pattern like the one shown below. The "%u" variable stands for "authenticated user". The link below lists all the other variables you can use.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
             directory="logs"  prefix="access." suffix=".log"
             pattern="%h %l %u %t '%r' %s %b"
             resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Comment: According to the link you provided, the common pattern already includes %u - "The shorthand pattern pattern="common" corresponds to the Common Log Format defined by '%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b'."  So how is this configuration any different?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="combined" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Would that do the trick as well ?